# Meaning of : will be being

Tags: grammar, future-perfect

Will be grateful for explanation of the grammar construction in following:

1. Our function WILL BE BEING an opposite way of advertisement agency.
2. You WILL BE BEING good examples of what to be.

3.They WILL BE BEING PERFORMED by the end of the year.

4. Students WILL BE BEING RELEASED shortly.
   The prices WILL BE BEING RAISED by more than a kopeck.

Comment: Who 'constructed' them?

Comment: #1 and #2 are totally non-idiomatic, and #3, #4 and #4a are relatively unlikely. Avoid all of them.

Comment: Hello Margarita and welcome to ELL! On this site, we answer questions about *specific aspects of English*. We do not explain the grammar of entire sentences, especially not sentences that you've made up and are not proper English. If you have a question about FUTURE CONTINUOUS PASSIVE, please frame your question around that concept, rather than asking for five sentences to be examined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Came across these sentences in a dictionary which considered trustful. Was unable to find any relevant explanation.

Comment: @Margarita What dictionary is it?

Comment: https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/

Answer (score 1):

The most likely use of this sequence is where *being* is part of a passive construction, as in your #3 and #4. But even in this construction it is only possible where the speaker is emphasizing that the activity will be either continuing at the particular moment, or continuing over some period.

For example

> When you arrive, the food will be being cooked.

emphasizes that the cooking will be going on at that very moment; and your #3 is possible only in the sense that there will be multiple performances over some period.

But even with these meanings, they are still not very likely things for anybody to say.

The active use of *being* (like your #1 and #2) is possible only in the special (rather colloquial) meaning of "behave in a certain way".

So you could say

> The twins will be being good.

meaning not just that they will behave properly, but that they will, over a period, repeatedly make an effort to behave properly.

This meaning is impossible in your examples, so they do not make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much!